# Layout: Text-View should scale automatically

Tags: android, xml, layout, textview

I created a layout, which has a imageview on the top, in the middle text and at the end a buttton. Now I want that all of these elements are on one page, that means the textview should scale his size automatically. Actually in my layout I only can see the imageview and the textview, for seeing the button I have to scroll.

Should I change the size of the textview by myself and adding different layouts for different screen sizes or is there another possibility?

My xml-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/l1"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/crunch1" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/button2links"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:scaleType="centerInside"
                        android:src="@drawable/links2" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:id="@+id/b2"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/l1"
                    android:orientation="horizontal" >

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/crunch2" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:id="@+id/button2rechts"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                        android:src="@drawable/rechts2" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Crunch"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/crunch" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/pause"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:onClick="verlaufKlick"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground" 
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

[image: That`s what I want!]

Comment: How many layouts did you use?!

Comment: 15 all of them with the same elements.

Comment: You only need **1**, to reproduce the given image...

Comment: i think you should use weight for that.. make three linearlayout..one for imageview, one for all textview and last for button.. and give height 0dp and weight according to your requirements.

Comment: Again... You only need **1** Layout, even if it is Linear instead of (what I would use, here, **Relative**). The weights go to the children.

Comment: @Vyger Can you please explain I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I don't use 15 layouts in this xml. I use 15 xml, which contains the same elements!

Comment: Your design is a BLOATWARE. Mine is LIGHTWEIGHT. 1 imageView is aligned to the top. 1 button is aligned to the bottom. 1 scrollview matches the remaining space in between. Then you attach the TextViews one below another... done! all this useless complication is gone away. BETTER if you were using a ListView instead of a ScrollView.

Comment: Now I used RelativeLayout with your settings, but not all of my text is shown and my text is under the button.

Answer (score 0):

Now I use this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

            <HorizontalScrollView
                android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >



                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/l1"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" >

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/crunch1" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/button2links"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                            android:scaleType="centerInside"
                            android:src="@drawable/links2" />


                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:src="@drawable/crunch2" />

                        <ImageView
                            android:id="@+id/button2rechts"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
                            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"                            
                            android:src="@drawable/rechts2" />
                    </RelativeLayout>

            </HorizontalScrollView>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:text="Crunch"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:layout_below="@+id/horizontalScrollView1" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:text="@string/crunch" 
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/pause"
                android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/pause"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                
                android:onClick="verlaufKlick"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                android:visibility="invisible"
                android:background="?android:selectableItemBackground"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"

                />


</RelativeLayout>
```